# How do I serve a specific file on my server as a specific path with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a website `example.com` and I want to serve the following file

`/home/myweb/path/file1.html`

as

`http://example.com/some/spec/path/`

It means, when people visit `http://example.com/some/spec/path/`, they will see the content of the `file1.html` on that page.

How should I config it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a specific `location` to match the URL. The block then contains a `root` and `try_files` statement to describe the file to be returned.

For example:

```
location = /some/spec/path/ {
    root /home/myweb/path;
    try_files /file1.html =404;
}
```

The `=404` will not be reached if the file exists, but is necessary as `try_files` requires at least two parameters and in this case `/file1.html` cannot be the last parameter.

See [the `location` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [the `try_files` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: Can I just use `try_files /home/myweb/path/file1.html =404;` and remove the `root` line?

Comment: No, `root` and `try_files` work together. `try_files` defines URIs and `root` converts them to path names. You could use `root /;` with your `try_files`. If you remove `root` it will inherit the value from the outer block. For example, if you are already using `root /home/myweb;` in the outer block, you can remove this `root` statement and use `try_files /path/file1.html =404;` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update. The rule works well as expected.